# Error trying to configure msstore-cli in my circleci environment

Tags: linux, windows, cicd, circleci

I am running this command in my circleci pipeline

`msstore reconfigure --tenantId $TENANT_ID --sellerId $SELLER_ID --clientId $CLIENT_ID --clientSecret $CLIENT_SECRET`

I am trying to configure my environment with msstore and configure my creedentials so that I can publish and release my app directly from my cli.

Even after confirming that my secrets are correct and installing the msstore-cli, I get this error.
I am using the circleci ubuntu image (default)

```
 __  __   _                                        __   _     
 |  \/  | (_)   ___   _ __    ___    ___    ___    / _| | |_   
 | |\/| | | |  / __| | '__|  / _ \  / __|  / _ \  | |_  | __|  
 | |  | | | | | (__  | |    | (_) | \__ \ | (_) | |  _| | |_   
 |_|  |_| |_|  \___| |_|     \___/  |___/  \___/  |_|    \__|  
                                                               
  ____    _                             ____                   
 / ___|  | |_    ___    _ __    ___    |  _ \    ___  __   __  
 \___ \  | __|  / _ \  | '__|  / _ \   | | | |  / _ \ \ \ / /  
  ___) | | |_  | (_) | | |    |  __/   | |_| | |  __/  \ V /   
 |____/   \__|  \___/  |_|     \___|   |____/   \___|   \_/    
                                                               
   ____   _       ___ 
  / ___| | |     |_ _|
 | |     | |      | | 
 | |___  | |___   | | 
  \____| |_____| |___|
                      

Use of the Microsoft Store Developer CLI is subject to the terms of the 
Microsoft Privacy Statement: https://aka.ms/privacy
You might need to provide some credentials to call the Microsoft Store APIs.
Let's start!

Unhandled exception: MSStore.API.MSStoreException: Failed to write credential
 ---> MSStore.API.MSStoreException: Failed to write credential: Domain: '137' - Code: '13' - Message: 'Address element “/dev/null” does not contain a colon (:)'
   at MSStore.CLI.Services.CredentialManager.Unix.CredentialManagerUnix.WriteCredentialLinux(String userName, String secret) in /_/MSStore.CLI/Services/CredentialManager/Unix/CredentialManagerUnix.cs:line 289
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MSStore.CLI.Services.CredentialManager.Unix.CredentialManagerUnix.WriteCredentialLinux(String userName, String secret) in /_/MSStore.CLI/Services/CredentialManager/Unix/CredentialManagerUnix.cs:line 293
   at MSStore.CLI.Services.CLIConfigurator.ConfigureAsync(Boolean askConfirmation, Nullable`1 tenantId, String sellerId, Nullable`1 clientId, String clientSecret, CancellationToken ct) in /_/MSStore.CLI/Services/CLIConfigurator.cs:line 278
   at MSStore.CLI.Commands.ReconfigureCommand.Handler.InvokeAsync(InvocationContext context) in /_/MSStore.CLI/Commands/ReconfigureCommand.cs:line 78
   at System.CommandLine.NamingConventionBinder.CommandHandler.GetExitCodeAsync(Object returnValue, InvocationContext context)
   at System.CommandLine.NamingConventionBinder.ModelBindingCommandHandler.InvokeAsync(InvocationContext context)
   at System.CommandLine.Invocation.InvocationPipeline.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<<BuildInvocationChain>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<<UseParseErrorReporting>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at MSStore.CLI.Program.<>c.<<Main>b__0_2>d.MoveNext() in /_/MSStore.CLI/Program.cs:line 229
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.CommandLine.Hosting.HostingExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<<UseHost>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<<UseHelp>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<<UseVersionOption>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<<UseTypoCorrections>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c.<<UseSuggestDirective>b__18_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<<UseParseDirective>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c.<<RegisterWithDotnetSuggest>b__5_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<<UseExceptionHandler>b__0>d.MoveNext()

Exited with code exit status 1
```